# Why this code is printing 20 20 instead of 20 10?

Tags: java

When I am calling the `getAge` and `superresult` methods, I am expecting *20 10* as output but the code is printing *20 20*. Why do I get a different result?

```
package package1;
public class MyClassA {
    protected int size;
    public MyClassA() {
    }
    protected int getAge() {
        return 10;
    }
    public int callAge() {
        return getAge();
    }
}

package package2;
import package1.MyClassA;
public class MyClassB extends MyClassA {
    protected int getAge() {
    return 20;
    }
    private int superesult() {
        return super.callAge();
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        MyClassB classb = new MyClassB();
        System.out.println(classb.getAge());
        System.out.println(classb.superesult());
    }
}
```

Comment: Because `getAge` is overriden.

Comment: `superresult` calls `callAge` in `MyClassA`, and `callAge` calls the overridden method `getAge`. The override in `MyClassB` returns 20. That's what overriding does.

Comment: "i am expecting 20 10" why do you expect such results?

Comment: @Pshemo: I think the OP has in mind that if you call something through `super` you "alter the context" in the sense that all calls are now in the "super domain".

Comment: The concept to understand here is called **polymorphism**. In the sense of: there isn't much sense in asking "why" are things this way; more like: that is how polymorphism manifests itself in Java. So you have to learn how that concept works; and then you will understand the behavior you are observing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Short answer**: you call the `callAge` as it is implemented in `A`. But that method calls `getAge` which is overriden (thus Java follows the implementation like it is done in `B`).

**Longer version**:

When you call:

```
classb.superesult();
```

It will invoke `super.callAge()`, so that means the `callAge()` of class `A` is executed. `callAge()` in his part invokes `getAge()` but since the object is an instance of class `B` and **`getAge()` is overridden**, it returns `20`.

Mind that if you call `super.foo()` you only call **the super foo**. `super` thus does **not mean that you "alter the context"**: all the calls that result out of the super call are still resolved through a dynamic binding on the object (and the object is still an instance of `B`). All calls `foo` does can be overriden (except if these are marked `final`). This is in most cases the desired bahavior.

Answer (score 3):

It's [polymorphism](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html). You have ovveridden in `getAge()` method. So when you call the method, the ovverdien method executes always.

> The Java virtual machine (JVM) calls the appropriate method for the object that is referred to in each variable. It does not call the method that is defined by the variable's type. This behavior is referred to as virtual method invocation and demonstrates an aspect of the important polymorphism features in the Java language.

Answer (score 1):

Its because you have override `getAge()` method in child class. Now as `MyClassB classb = new MyClassB();` is pointing to child class, so its method will be called instead of parent method